# R add values to function if threshhold is met

Tags: r

I am writing a function that test's alot of variables via:

```
test_function <- function(value1, value2){
    test <- summary(lm(formula = value1 ~ value2, data = df1))$adj.r.squared
}

value1 <- unique(df1$column1)
value2 <- unique(df1$column2)

adj_R <- list()

for (i in value1){
      for(b in value2){
        adj_R[[i]] =
          test_function (i, b)
      }
    } 

do.call(...)
```

I will run this with a for loop to loop through all variables that need to be tested. But what I want to do is if test > 0.5 add it to a new dataframe. so all variables that score > 0.5 will be in a new dataframe. Should I make a list within my for loop that adds

and so what I would like to do is add the tested values with there corresponding adjusted squared R to a new dataframe. But on that part i am kind of running in to trouble. How should I approach this?

Comment: In your code, you have twice `i` used for each loop, this won't work. Also you have nothing called `b`, shouldn't it be `for(b in value2)`?

Comment: @YacineHajji Good spot! yes this is a typo on my end.

Comment: @YacineHajji it is a dataframe. My code is not finished. As I stated I would like to add some things but I do not know how to implement.

Comment: 'so what I would like to do is add the tested values with there corresponding adjusted squared R'. What is the expected output for this, a list of data-frames with each list being called after the 2 variables and their r-squared?

Comment: @YacineHajji thank you for your input. I created a empty dataframe before the function and added the following code in my function:: if (test > 0.5){
    datalist <<- rbind(datalist, bro) with datalist being my empty dataframe and bro a dataframe I created in the function with the variables

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I simplified the code

The following code will launch a loop where you compute r-squared only on the remaining columns of your data-frame

```
### Simulating data
df1 <- data.frame(A=rnorm(10),
                  B=rnorm(10),
                  C=rnorm(10),
                  D=rnorm(10))

### Initiating all possible scenarios
adj_Rtemp <- expand.grid(colnames(df1), colnames(df1))
adj_R <- subset(adj_Rtemp, Var1!=Var2)
adj_R$rSquared <- NA

### Loop to fill rsquared values
for (i in 1:nrow(adj_R)){
      df <- df1[, c(adj_R$Var1[i], adj_R$Var2[i])]  # keeping only variables of interest
      adj_R$rSquared[i] <- summary(lm(data = df))$adj.r.squared
}

### Keeping only rows with a rSquared>=0.5
subset(adj_R, rSquared>=0.5)

### Output
Var1 Var2  rSquared
3     C    A 0.5214252
7     C    B 0.5214252
15    C    D 0.1332496

### New data-frame
df1[, unique(c(subset(adj_R, rSquared>=0.5)$Var1, subset(adj_R, rSquared>=0.5)$Var2))]

### Output
        C           A           B
1  -1.8510475  1.23193804  0.79704725
2   0.2655458  0.73543648  0.17667941
3  -0.4189463 -0.33159445 -1.75986213
4   1.9880595  1.70937888  1.56504084
5   0.7754711 -0.64304919 -0.09848331
6  -1.2911590  1.10990065 -0.20437612
7   1.3221721  0.38382927  0.36282622
8   0.7928655 -0.69570801 -0.55898156
9   0.3875522  0.07025441  0.49354454
10 -0.4971241  2.00613047  1.35257274
```